# How to read the randomly/dynamic xml tag name that i don't know?

Tags: php, xml, tags, tagname

I would like to perform a xml data exchange as below:

The incoming xml data have some tags i don't know about the tag name.

Can i read those tag without knowing the tag name? 
Also how can i get the tag name as the data attribute?

For example:
i want to read different patients record. Every patient have different disease. Such as 'Heart Disease', 'cancer'.

```
<heart disease>serious</heart disease>
<cancer>normal</cancer>
```

I don't know both tags before. but i want to read the tag name and present it.
Finally, i can get data:
heart disease: serious
cancer normal:

Comment: Hint: Check the validity of your xml here: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel that I should first warn you that white-space does not make for valid XML tags. You can add `<white space>STUFF</white space>`, but that will read as a `<white>` tag. With a more forgiving interpreter, you might find that it has a true `space` boolean attribute. Replace the `\s` with `-`.

With DOMDocument, to read child nodes without knowing anything about them, other than the fact that they are child nodes, you would use the appropriately named `childNodes` property:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$rand = rand(1,100);
$doc->loadXML('<root><i'.$rand.'><cannot-know-i /></i'.$rand.'></root>');
foreach( $doc->documentElement->childNodes as $node )
    print $node->nodeName; // i$rand
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, e.g. with Simple XML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($fileName, NULL, true);

foreach ($xml->children() as $child)
{
    print child->getName();

    foreach ($child->attributes() as $attribute)
    {
        print $attribute.', ';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you format the XML into another format. In a format you DO know. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
    <Information>
        <Disease target="heart" />
        <Cancer type="normal" />
    </Information>
</xml>
```

Then you can use every parser that is available in your programming language (PHP in your case).